# Razor rendering in jsx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, razor

I'm trying to have a Navbar fixed in my MVC web app.
Is there a way I can have something like this in my **_Layout.cshtml** ?

Just looking to take advantage of the Razor Engine.

```
const navbarInstance = (
  <Navbar>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href="#">My Web Abb</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="@Url.Action("Index1","Controller")">Link1</NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="@Url.Action("Index2","Controller")">Link2</NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar>
);

ReactDOM.render(navbarInstance, navbar);
```

Comment: That looks correct. What result do you get? You can use pretty much anything that resolves on the initial load of a view safely with razor.

Comment: I've enclosed the code above within `<script type="text/jsx">` and added a  `<script src="JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>` (which I would like to avoid if possible)
But the browser won't recognize `"imports"`

Comment: Do I have to use React JS.Net to achieve this?

I have webpack configured to pick up all the other .jsx files I have.
I just wanted to take advantage of razor and I can't do that in plain jsx. so I have to do it inside a .cshtml

Comment: You can use this within a script tag within your page (within a cshtml view file), but not within you JSX file, because it will be rendered on the server first.  The only way to do this would be to use ReactJS.net properly and pass the values through from your model as initial props.

Comment: I am a dope! I just realized that would be outside of the scope of a partial. Or rather not included in the rendering of the partial. I thought a while back that I used external templates that had razor markup that was evaluated in the parent partial view. I know realize that it was  Razor in JS functions, however, the JS has to be inside a cshtml view, not an external reference.